# Combobox initialization

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm using a ComboBox to display a list of ZoomLevels (e.g. normal, large, xxl), the selected ZoomLevel is bound to the variable "ZoomLevel" in my MainViewModel.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ZoomLevels}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding ZoomLevel}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedValuePath="Name"/>
```

On application start, the initial ZoomLevel is loaded from the settings and might be set to "xxl", e.g.

**My problem is that during initialization of the ComboBox, the setter of "ZoomLevel" is called with the first ZoomLevel in the bound collection "ZoomLevels".**

This overwrites the value for "ZoomLevel" loaded from the settings and it's always the first ZoomLevel that is selected in the combobox.

What is the problem here? If I  remove `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`, then the ZoomLevel is initialized correctly. However, the Combobox is then not in sync with the currently selected ZoomLevel, which it should be.

EDIT: relevant code from my MainViewModel:

```
public class ZoomLevel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double ZoomLevelValue { get; set; } 
}

    public MainViewModel() 
    {
     ...
            // Load zoom level
            var userDefinedZoom = ZoomLevels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ZoomLevelValue == Settings.Default.ZoomLevelValue);
            ZoomLevel = userDefinedZoom ?? ZoomLevels[0];
     }

    /// <summary>
    /// Zoom level of application, initialized in the constructor
    /// </summary>
    private ZoomLevel _zoomLevel;
    public ZoomLevel ZoomLevel
    {
        get { return _zoomLevel; }
        set
        {
            _zoomLevel = value;

            Settings.Default.ZoomLevelValue = value.ZoomLevelValue;
            Settings.Default.Save();

            RaisePropertyChanged("ZoomLevel");
        }


    /// <summary>
    /// all available zoom levels
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<ZoomLevel> ZoomLevels
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<ZoomLevel>()
            {
                new ZoomLevel() { Name="normal", ZoomLevelValue = 1 },
                new ZoomLevel() { Name="large", ZoomLevelValue = 1.2 },
                new ZoomLevel() { Name="xxl", ZoomLevelValue = 1.4 },
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you please post your C# code?

Comment: The `ZoomLevel` property value must be a member of the `ZoomLevels` collection (not anything else like `new ZoomLevel(...)`). Besides that, neither setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` nor `SelectedValuePath` is necessary here.

Comment: You dont post the `ZoomLevel` class

Comment: Hi Clemens, I've added some details. The 'ZoomLevel' is a member of the 'ZoomLevels' collection. I have removed 'SelectedValuePath', when I remove 'IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem', then there is no value selected in the ComboBox at first.

Comment: Sakura, I've added the class.

Comment: Hmm might it be the problem that I am returning a new ObservableCollection<ZoomLevel>() .. then, ZoomLevel is not part of the collection.. as you said, Clemens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectedItem` must be a member of the `ItemsSource` collection.

You should therefore initialize the `ZoomLevel` property with that instance of the `ZoomLevels` that corresponds to the current default value:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    ZoomLevels = new List<ZoomLevel>()
    {
        new ZoomLevel { Name = "normal", ZoomLevelValue = 1 },
        new ZoomLevel { Name = "large", ZoomLevelValue = 1.2 },
        new ZoomLevel { Name = "xxl", ZoomLevelValue = 1.4 },
    };

    // here
    ZoomLevel = ZoomLevels.FirstOrDefault(
        z => z.ZoomLevelValue == Settings.Default.ZoomLevelValue);
}

public List<ZoomLevel> ZoomLevels { get; private set; }
```

Note also that if the `ZoomLevels` collection never changes, it is not necessary that it is an ObservableCollection.

Besides that, setting the `SelectedValuePath` of the ComboBox only makes sense in conjunction with `SelectedValue`. As you are using `SelectedItem`, it is redundant.